# How do I create a dynamic web page that will list all XML files in a directory?

Tags: xml, html, xslt, dom

I have approximately 200 XML files in a directory that change periodically.  The goal is to have a "Home Page" that grabs a 'title' element from each XML file and then creates a dynamic table of contents -- I'd rather not manually edit an new HTML "Home Page" each time a file is changed, deleted or added.

Any suggestions?  Attempts to search for an answer have proven pretty fruitless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need some kind of server-side method of getting a listing of files.  One possible candidate (which you **could** use XSLT to transform) would be your HTTP server's default method of showing a directory listing (you'd need to allow access to directory listing for that file, and you could specify some kind of XSLT in your default directory listing to transform it to look like what you want in your home page).  However, this feels a little clunky and may not be compatible with other security policies you want to have.

If you have access to some other server side technology (php, Ruby, Python, Perl, ASP.NET, etc.), there's probably a clearer/more maintainable way of doing this.   But using **only** the technologies you listed it's not possible (without at least a little help from your httpd).

Answer (score 0):

Very late reply but hopefully people who will come in future could make use of this.

I think you could do it easily with node. Here's a snippet which will loop through the directory which you pass and load it in an array

```
var fs = require('fs'); // import file system
var path = require('path'); //import path, used to resolve file path

var dir = <MAIN_DIR_PATH>; // DIr path were you want to search the xml file
var xmlFile = []; //Array in which xml file will be stored
logFileSystem(dir);

// Recursively checks for xml 
function logFileSystem(dirPath) {
    //Read the firectory
    fs.readdir(dirPath, function(err, files) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Could not read dir", err);
            return;
        }
        //Loop through each file
        files.forEach(function(file, index) {
            var filePath = path.join(dirPath, file);
            fs.stat(filePath, function(err, stat) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("Error stating file", err);
                }
                if (stat.isFile()) {
                    if (filePath.endsWith("xml")) {
                        console.log("This is xml file = ",filePath)
                        xmlFile.push(filePath)
                    }


                }
                // If directory call the api again recursively
                if (stat.isDirectory()) {
                    logFileSystem(filePath);
                }
            })
        })
    })

}
```

You could now return this to the user via an api call. Creating an api with node is really simple.

Hopefully this post will help someone to get job done.